# Running the selected code in Sublime Text

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext3

I have created a "build system" in Sublime Text 3 like so:

```
{
    "cmd": ["node", "$file"]
}
```

I have a file `foo.js` containing two lines:

```
01    console.log('foo');
02    console.log('bar');
```

If I highlight line 1. Can I run just that line in the build system?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this is just what you need:
http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=29006

The [BuildParts](https://github.com/erinata/BuildParts) plugin allows you to run only the selected piece of code, but now does not support multiple selections.

Comment: Please summarize the relevant parts of the link in your answer. This answer would be useless if the link changes or is unavailable (as the Sublime forum routinely is). Please see [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) on [meta.se] for more information on link-only answers.

Comment: This answer has become far out of date. BuildParts hasn't been updated in the last 7 years and does not appear to work with Sublime Text 3.

Comment: I used BuildParts on 7/11/2019 in Sublime Text 3 and it worked great.